# How to merge multiple result rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, codeigniter, activerecord

Here is what I want to do: I have the following tables:

```
User
id     name  
1      user1


Emails
id     email                           user_id
1      something@somewhere.com         1
2      something_else@somewhere.com    1

Addresses
id    address  user_id
 1    Here     1
 2    There    1
```

What I want to do is a SELECT that contains only one row per user, no matter how many emails and addresses he has. The problem is that I also need one address to be visible. So I need my result to look like this:

```
name         email                address  total_emails total_addresses
user1        something@somewhere  Here     2            2
```

I thought of GROUP BY, but since I use the COUNT function to get the number of emails and addresses, I am forced to GROUP BY all the columns and therefore get a result per combination...

Is what I want to do even possible in SQL? Is it possible using CodeIgniter ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with sql-server but in mysql i would write this:

```
SELECT t1.id AS user_id, 
       t2.email AS user_email,
       t3.address AS user_address,
       (SELECT count(*) from emails WHERE user_id = t1.id) as total_emails,
       (SELECT count(*) from emails WHERE user_id = t1.id) as total_addresses,
FROM user t1
LEFT JOIN emails t2 on t1.id = t2.user_id
LEFT JOIN addresses t3 ON t1.id = t3.user_id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

If sql server supports subqueries it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
;With user_details AS
(
SELECT
name
,_Addresses.address
,_email.email
,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY _email.id ASC) AS email_row
,COUNT(_email.email) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS email_count
,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY _addresses.id ASC) AS address_row
,COUNT(_addresses.address) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS address_count
FROM _user
LEFT OUTER JOIN _email on _email.user_id = _user.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN _Addresses ON _Addresses.user_id = _user.id
)
SELECT 
name
,MAX(CASE WHEN email_row = 1 THEN email END) AS email
,MAX(CASE WHEN address_row = 1 THEN address END) AS address
,MAX(email_count) as total_emails
,MAX(address_count) as total_addresses
FROM user_details
GROUP BY name
```